# how to add one object to queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
oldHref = c.common.externalLinks.all()
newHref = m.common.externalLinks.all()
m.common.externalLinks = list(chain(oldHref,newHref))
```

This compiles and works fine.

But what I want to do is

```
for x in oldHref:
    if ... :
        m.common.externalLinks = list(chain(newHref, x))
```

This does not compile.

Just to give you an idea of their types:

```
m.common.externalLinks.all() =  [<List: List object>] #same as newHref
x =  List object
```

Comment: What do you mean `this does not compile`? What error does it give?

Comment: `...` of type `ellipsis` always evaluates to `True`. Hence you can save this line.

Comment: TypeError: 'List' object is not iterable. I actaully have some conditions check for '...'.

Comment: "TypeError: 'List' object is not iterable" This is the error message I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but I think you are trying to get the union of two querysets.

If this is the case, you can use:

```
c.common.externalLinks.all() | m.common.externalLinks.all()
```

An alternative may be to use:

```
ExternalLink.objects.filter(common__in=[m.common, c.common])
```

But that will depend on what the rest of your code looks like.

An aside on python style: try to use `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`.

Okay, it's not the union you want: perhaps you want to add all of the values from `m.common.externalLinks.all()` into `c.common.externalLinks`?

```
c.common.externalLinks.add(*m.common.externalLinks.all())
```

Or, if you only want the first one:

```
c.common.externalLinks.add(m.common.externalLinks.all()[0])
```

Comment: Adding two querysets work fine. I mean adding .all() and .all() works fine. But when I try to add one object to .all(), it give me this error message, "TypeError: 'List' object is not iterable."

Comment: By one object, I mean, like m.common.externalLinks.all()[0].

Comment: Do you want to add one of the objects from m.common.externalLinks.all() to c.common.externalLinks.all(), so that this value is persisted in the database? It's still not completely clear to me what you are wanting to achieve, rather than how you are trying to do it.